# Error in `sudo yum -y update`

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum

I am getting following error while updating my amazon EC2 instance.

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/pyrsa-decrypt conflicts between attempted installs of python2-rsa-3.4.1-1.el6.noarch and python26-rsa-3.4.1-1.8.amzn1.noarch
  file /usr/bin/pyrsa-decrypt-bigfile conflicts between attempted installs of python2-rsa-3.4.1-1.el6.noarch and python26-rsa-3.4.1-1.8.amzn1.noarch
  file /usr/bin/pyrsa-encrypt conflicts between attempted installs of python2-rsa-3.4.1-1.el6.noarch and python26-rsa-3.4.1-1.8.amzn1.noarch
  file /usr/bin/pyrsa-encrypt-bigfile conflicts between attempted installs of python2-rsa-3.4.1-1.el6.noarch and python26-rsa-3.4.1-1.8.amzn1.noarch
  file /usr/bin/pyrsa-keygen conflicts between attempted installs of python2-rsa-3.4.1-1.el6.noarch and python26-rsa-3.4.1-1.8.amzn1.noarch
  file /usr/bin/pyrsa-priv2pub conflicts between attempted installs of python2-rsa-3.4.1-1.el6.noarch and python26-rsa-3.4.1-1.8.amzn1.noarch
  file /usr/bin/pyrsa-sign conflicts between attempted installs of python2-rsa-3.4.1-1.el6.noarch and python26-rsa-3.4.1-1.8.amzn1.noarch
  file /usr/bin/pyrsa-verify conflicts between attempted installs of python2-rsa-3.4.1-1.el6.noarch and python26-rsa-3.4.1-1.8.amzn1.noarch
```

I tried

`sudo yum remove python26-rsa-3.4.1-1.8.amzn1.noarch`

But error is not gone.

My Linux machine information:

```
$cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by self.
change `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` as following

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
enabled=1
# ------^------- set this to zero
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

Comment: For the benefit of others, please explain *how* you fixed it. Without that information this is not an answer.